# How to shrink the size of div containing the table

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have HTML markup below. I need to cut the size of div containing the table to half so basically overflow: hidden and only show a part of div contained within the specified size. However height property on the containing div is not being applied to the table.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .temp{
            height: 20px;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="temp">
      <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>This is a test.</td>
        <td>Do you see what I mean?</td>
        <td>I hate this overflow.</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your example produces one line of text.  Do you want it to show only the top half of the text?

Comment: Stupid me.... it was obvious...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   .temp{
        height: 15px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }​
```

this will cut the one line of text you have in half , if that's what you want .  Are you sure you didn't mean

```
          <tr>
             <td>This is a test.</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>Do you see what I mean?</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>I hate this overflow.</td>
          </tr>
```

to make 3 rows , then hide some of it?

Answer (score 1):

Uhhh - not sure if I'm misunderstanding you, but just adding overflow:hidden; is doing the job for me. [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mxcrh/).